# Laravel Route::controller completion in PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I'm looking for a solution for better code navigation within routes definition in PhpStorm.

Using "array convention":

```
Route::get('endpoint', [Controller::class, 'get']);
Route::put('endpoint', [Controller::class, 'put']);
```

I can quickly jump to `get` or `put` methods from an editor. However, I want to use  `Route::controller` more often:

```
Route::controller(Controller::class)->group(function() {
  Route::get('endpoint', 'get');
  Route::put('endpoint', 'put');
});
```

But this solution allows me to jump to controller class only, not to methods directly.

I have enabled `Laravel support` in settings. PhpStorm 2022.2.

Comment: `[Controller::class, 'put']` -- this is generic PHP stuff, not linked to any framework; such navigation is provided by PhpStorm core. What you are asking -- it's specific to Laravel and therefore better be asked in Laravel-specific plugin. *"I have enabled Laravel support in settings."* PhpStorm does not have any specific Laravel support. Which Laravel plugin you have got there?

Comment: I've just figured out that after updating to 2022.2, the Laravel plugin is not compatible anymore. I used "official" plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532-laravel/ before.

Comment: Yes. That plugin have not seen any updates for a while. Its GitHub repo is in archive/read-inly state. I suggest you check **Laravel Idea** plugin instead. Only one issue -- it's a PAID plugin, but it is in active development, has many features (much more than Laravel one) and well worth the money for Laravel devs. Give it a try (trial period).

Comment: @LazyOne, thank you, **Laravel Idea solves my problem**. That paid plugin is not an issue - I favor supporting helpful software. However, I need to dive deeper because I see more fancy features that this plugin provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Controller::class, 'put']` -- this is generic PHP stuff, not linked to any framework and therefore such navigation is provided by PhpStorm core.

However using `Route::controller(Controller::class)` grouping is specific to Laravel. PhpStorm does not provide any Laravel-specific support (excluding Blade files). Therefore such navigation should be coming from a Laravel specific plugin.

The original **Laravel plugin** is no longer compatible with the 2022.2 version: the latest version was released like 3 years ago (back in 2019) and [its GitHub repo](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-laravel-plugin) is in archived/read-only state now (*"This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only."*).

I suggest you check **[Laravel Idea plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13441-laravel-idea)** instead. It supports such navigation. Please note: it's a PAID plugin, but it is in active development, has many features (much more than the original Laravel plugin) and well worth the money for devs using Laravel framework.